# PHP PDO error when using placeholders in the LIMIT clause of a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT sql_calc_found_rows * FROM members".
       " ORDER BY username LIMIT :startRow, :numRows";

try {
    $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindParam(":startRow", $startRow, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->bindParam(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Here I get error:

> Query failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1.

The `LIMIT :startRow, :numRows` has problem in `:numRows`.

I have tried both `$st->bindParam` and `$st->bindValue`, both didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to remove th blank between `:startRow, :numRows`

Comment: SELECT sql_calc_found_rows * FROM ?? what is this?

Comment: Jens, I have tried but it wont work.it only shows problem in :numRows.

Comment: error is because of $order please put static value for testing. rest everything is looks perfect

Comment: Danyal value of $order is "username"
and sql_calc_found_rows is sql function to retrieve the number of rows in table i guess

Comment: I have tested your sql query there is no error try remove order for testing. i think thats causing problem

Comment: kamlesh.bar , this is a public static function with parameters $startRow, $numRows, $order.

Comment: I understand it's public static function there is nothing wrong with that as you mention you have mysql error and i think problem lies near $order variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78496/discussion-between-sujin-shrestha-and-kamlesh-bar).

Comment: you should add your answer below and you can accept your answer that way you can imporve your score

Comment: not like this you can answer your question in below Box "your Answer" and than accept by click on right image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78588/discussion-between-sujin-shrestha-and-kamlesh-bar).

Comment: @Marcin  where's the exact question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it.I Type casted the `:numRows` placeholder.

```
$numRows=(int)$numRows;
$sql = 'SELECT sql_calc_found_rows * FROM ' . 
    TBL_MEMBERS .'ORDER BY'.  $order .'LIMIT :startRow,:numRows';
    try {
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":startRow", $startRow, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
    ...
```

And it worked. I also noticed the `'` should be use instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with TBL_MEMBERS
I suppose this is a view(subselect).
So, if you have product table for example and you want to execute following statement:

```
select sql_calc_found_rows * from select id, code, name, slug, info from products order by code
```

you will receive following error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id, code, name, slug, info from products order by code' at line 1

But if you change query to:

```
select sql_calc_found_rows * from (select id, code, name, slug, info from products) v order by code
```

this will work.

To summarize,
TBL_MEMBERS is a view which should be put in parenthesis and given alias(i my example alias is 'v')

Comment: `TBL_MEMBERS` is a definition.
    `define("TBL_MEMBERS","members");`
I dont think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look at the SQL query text what PDO actually produces. You can do this with help of MySQL's [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Most probably, the formal types of `$startRow` and/or `$numRows` are strings, not integers, and resulting query is therefore something like `LIMIT '0', '5'` (syntax error) instead of `LIMIT 0, 5` (correct).

The thing is, even with `PDO::PARAM_INT`, when the parameter's formal type is not integer ([`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) returns `false`), PDO wraps it in quotes. So, you have to cast parameters to integers before binding them (e.g. using [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)):

```
$st->bindParam(":startRow", intval(trim($startRow)), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindParam(":numRows", intval(trim($numRows)), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```